# How to call the php code from an action in the same file

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="??" method="post">
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    //php
?>
```

Now, how Can I run a php in the same file? Because If I want to call it from another file for example 'something.php' I'll put in the form `action="something.php'` and it will work.

I am new in php and my english is not good so it is difficult for me to explain you. I was looking for this answer on this page but there is nothing what Can I understand.

I don't want to send the code because most of it is in Polish so it wouldn't make sense. This form will be used to send an email.

Comment: Try `action=""` it will defaul to this file

Comment: Yes. You can omit the action completely or just fill in the file name, and the data will be posted to the same php file.

Comment: `<form action="same_file_as_you_called.php" method="post">` will also work, putting your html/php in the same file.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave out the `action` attribute completely, the form will post to the same page:

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP,submit form in same page then you should try below

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

Comment: Safer to use `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` as short tags are not always activated in PHP

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly but now in day most server has upgraded version of PHP so it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
```

The `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is a super global variable that returns the filename of the currently executing script.